# use ros in handheld device

Tags: navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently  working on a project with Ridgeback Clearpath robot. I need to command a Ridgeback robot to get to pre-defined selected point with an Android device.  It also need to tell robot to either pick or place when it gets there. I can get to the point that able to control Ridgeback on RVIZ and have a code for it to self-navigation to certain location in the map. However, I am not sure how to run all of these commands in an Android device. Any ideas would greatly appropriated. thank in advance.

My OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS;
Version of ROS : Indigo;
Package using: Navigation package for Ridgeback and I use gmapping to get the map for robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271183/use-ros-in-handheld-device/) by [kimnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31650/kimnguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at http://wiki.ros.org/android? Just click the tab that says "Indigo" and you'll see a bunch of text including tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1